# Jenkins failed to find a valid Java installation

Tags: jenkins

How to debug why Jenkins can't see Java? I have:
jenkins-2.387.3 and manually extracted JRE11 as it described in [requirenments](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/). I can't understand how Jenkins trying to find it.

```bash
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.18" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment BiSheng_JDK_Enterprise_2.3.0.360.B001 (build 11.0.18+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM BiSheng_JDK_Enterprise_2.3.0.360.B001 (build 11.0.18+10, mixed mode)
```

I see in journal:

```bash
jenkins[9063]: jenkins: failed to find a valid Java installation
systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start My Company Jenkins Controller.
```

```bash
● jenkins.service - My Company Jenkins Controller
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-05-17 21:28:51 CST; 5min ago
  Process: 11759 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 11759 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

```bash
systemctl edit jenkins.service

[Unit]
Description=My Company Jenkins Controller

[Service]
# Add JVM configuration options
Environment="JAVA_HOME=/root/jre-11.0.18"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

Comment: Since i see `root` in the path, under what user are you starting jenkins and does that user have the rights to access that JAVA_HOME path?